# TypeScript Inline static type guard

Tags: typescript

```
type MyType = {
  name: string,
  content: string | undefined
}

function doThing(baz: string) {...}

function foo(bar: MyType) {
  if(bar.name === "goodName") {
    doThing(bar.content) //Error
  }
}
```

I have a function named foo, which takes one argument of bar, which is of type MyType. Some instances of MyType don't have the `content` property defined, but I know for a fact that the instance where `bar.name === "goodName"` does have its `content` property defined. TypeScript, however, does not know this, and throws an error in the above code. How can I express that bar.content is a string to TypeScript in such a fashion:

```
if(bar.name === "goodName") {
  bar.content is string; //Hypothetical
  doThing(bar.content); //No error; the desired outcome
}
```

Does such a feature exist in TypeScript? I'm aware of user-defined type guards for functions, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way of doing it in a specific case like this one (it only has to be used in `foo`).

Comment: TypeScript's discriminated unions need the distriminating member to have a literal type. Having `name` declared as `string` won't allow you to do what you want. See: https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/types/discriminated-unions.md

Answer (score 2):

If you have only a limited number of options for `name` you can use a discriminated union:

```
type MyTypeBadName = {
  name: 'badName',
}
type MyTypeGoodName = {
  name: 'goodName',
  content: string
}

function doThing(baz: string) {}

function foo(bar: MyTypeBadName | MyTypeGoodName) {
  if(bar.name === "goodName") {
    doThing(bar.content) //ok
  }
}
```

Otherwise you can use a custom type guard to change the type of bar:

```
type MyType = {
  name: string,
  content: string | undefined
}


type MyTypeGoodName = {
  name: 'goodName',
  content: string
}

function isGoodName(baz: MyType): baz is MyTypeGoodName {
  return baz.name == "goodName"
}
function doThing(s: string) { }

function foo(bar: MyType) {
  if(isGoodName(bar)) {
    doThing(bar.content) //ok
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this for optional properties or this wont suit your case:

```
type MyType = {
  name: string,
  content?: string
}

function doThing(baz: string) {...}

function foo(bar: MyType) {
  if(bar.name === "goodName") {
    doThing(bar.content) //Error
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have easy access to the definition for MyType, so unfortunately I can't use that. I think it would still cause issues if I did, since `content` is concatenated with a string in `doThing`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) `!`. From the docs:

> A new ! post-fix expression operator may be used to assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined in contexts where the type checker is unable to conclude that fact. Specifically, the operation x! produces a value of the type of x with null and undefined excluded.

I think this is exactly your use-case.

```
function foo(bar: MyType) {
  if(bar.name === "goodName") {
    doThing(bar!.content) // Let the compiler know content will always be defined
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of doing an inline type guard is to use the `in` operator. In your example, the code should look as follows:

```js
function foo(bar: MyTypeBadName | MyTypeGoodName) {
  if('content' in bar) {
    doThing(bar.content) //ok
  }
}
```